# Measure the mass of an electron from annihilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The question ask: "Is it possible to precisely measure the mass of an electron up to five significant figures by measuring the energy distribution of the photons created in electron-positron annihilation?"
My question is that what exactly is the energy distribution of photons here?

Comment: An energy distribution is a function or plot (we often say "histogram") of the number (or fraction) of particles that have a particular energy (or more properly an energy in some small range) as a function of that energy.

Comment: Got it, thank you! So how does this function contributes to measuring the mass of an electron?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?  There exist electron mass measurements to [great accuracy](https://www.mpg.de/7961020/electron-mass), a mass 1/1836.15267377 that of a proton , [or 0.000548579909067](http://www.zmescience.com/science/physics/mass-of-electron-most-precise-measurement-052435/) of an atomic mass unit.